# python celsius to fahrenheit

Tags: python

I have an error message when I run my code.

Here is my code:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32

print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-280))

if celsius < -273.15:
    return "That's impossible"
else:
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5+32
    return fahrenheit
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-273.4))
```

Here is the error message:

```
File "./exercise1.py", line 7
    return "That's impossible"
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure you use Python 3.x. In Python 2.7, `9/5` is 1. Better change it to `9.0/5` to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this with proper indent

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32



    if celsius < -273.15:
        return "That's impossible"
    else:
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5+32
        return fahrenheit
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-273.4))
```

Comment: Yep.  Without the indentation, the `return` is not inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

My answer corrects the answer given by nishant (improving the indentation),

Try this one:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32

    if celsius < -273.15:
        return "That's impossible"
    else:
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5+32
        return fahrenheit
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-273.4))
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-280))
```

Let me know how it works

Comment: You would be better off editing and improving his answer rather than posting a duplicate answer

Comment: I posted the answer before his editing, thats why it's appearing that I have posted a duplicate answer

Comment: Understood. I didn't check the timestamp on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is important in Python.  Since your first `print` statement has the same indentation as your 'def', Python assumes that your function is already over.  So make sure everything that should be in your function is properly indented.

In fact, the first print statement doesn't seem to belong there.  Putting that sort of call to the function within the function itself will cause everything to loop.  Also:

- There's no need to check the `else`.  If the check for absolute zero passes, you exit the function at that point anyway.
- There's no need to do the calculation twice.
- Python, at least in 2.x versions, doesn't automatically switch to float when doing integer arithmetic. So putting in 11 for example gives different results than 11.0 for some versions.  You can force Python to use floats though if you replace `9` with `9.0`, or just replace `9/5` with `1.8`.

So here's a short version that works:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):    
    if celsius < -273.15:
        return "That's impossible"    
    return celsius * 9.0/5 + 32

print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-50))
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted, your function contains a single line of code, and the rest of the code will be executed immediately.

Like the error message says, you can't `return` when you are not inside a function.

*Probably* you meant most (but not all) of the code to be part of the function. Here is a somewhat speculative refactoring, with comments.

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    # Don't perform this calculation twice
    # fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32
    # Don't attempt to call the function from within its own definition
    if celsius < -273.15:
        # raise an error instead of returning a bogus value
        raise ValueError("Temperature below absolute zero")
    else:
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5+32
        return fahrenheit

# We are now outside the function definition.
# Call the function twice to see that it works.    
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-273.4))

# Should throw an error:
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-280))
```

Answer (score 0):

To break down some of the errors in your code:

**1: No `return` statement**

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32

print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-280))
```

In this block you need to include a `return` function

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32
    return fahrenheit

print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-280))
```

**2: Improper indentation or no function defined**

```
if celsius < -273.15:
    return "That's impossible"
else:
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5+32
    return fahrenheit
```

For this block of code because you haven't indented it correctly, it is not executed as a part of the function call. The reason for your error is because you are trying to `return` something that doesn't exist inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the redundant code. Fix the indentation and you can use:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    if celsius < -273.15:
        return "That's impossible"
    else:
        return celsius * 9/5+32
print(celsius_to_fahrenheit(-273.4))
```